# Interacting with paper.js paperscript from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

Looking for a graphics library to make an online HTML game with Socket.IO. Can you manipulate a "paperscript" context from regular JavaScript? I've been reading the paper.js documentation and see nothing about sending data to a paperscript. Is a paperscript a closed program that is separate from JS?

I did read that paperscript can be used [directly from JS](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/), but this seems to be a messy / cumbersome solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using paper.js directly in javascript is really simple, the only important thing you loose is the operator overloads (you must write PointA.add(PointB) instead of PointA + PointB). I have used it a lot in pure JS and never had a problem.

[Here](http://scratchdisk.com/posts/operator-overloading) is the article which explains the differences between paperscript and javascript.

Comment: I setup a "paperscript" and I also learned you can use regular JS from the paperscript. I loaded JQuery and the ready command fired, so I'm assuming other non-paper JS works there too. However, I did notice that global variables don't work. Only the paper object is global according to the documentation.

Comment: yes, but you can use [paper.install(window)](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscope/#install-scope) as explained [here](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/) @ *Making the Scope Global*.